# Diagonal brush style gives me black area

Tags: delphi, canvas, styles, brush

I want to draw a diagonal cross into a Canvas with this code:

```
InFlateRect(r, -1, -1);
Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
Canvas.Brush.Style := bsFDiagonal;
Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
//Pen.Style := psClear;
Canvas.Rectangle(r);
```

But the result is a black box.

If I remove the style changing, a normal solid yellow area I got.

Why is the rectangle black with this code?

Thanks for every suggestion

---

Sorry for missing info, I extend it:
This procedure is using TMetaFileCanvas to draw. On normal Form I can draw any brush style, like the TShape...

Comment: Your code produces red border and yellow diagonal lines on the light gray background (form.color) for me (delphi 7, win xp)

Comment: what is brush.width or pen.width or something like that ?

Comment: oops, i messed with TPen.Style

Comment: What device are you drawing to? Not all devices support all brush or pen styles.

Comment: Another issue with devices: hatched brush pattern always uses device coordinates, not logical, so small-pixel device, e.g. printer, may produce weird result

Comment: I draw it into a MetaFile canvas (DeviceHandle = 0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
procedure TForm4.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R := ClientRect;
  InflateRect(R, -10, -10);
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsFDiagonal;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Rectangle(R);
end;
```

produces the result

[image: Screenshot]

(Don't forget to `Invalidate` in the form's `OnResize`.)

Notice that the area is filled with diagonal yellow lines. This is indeed what the `bsFDiagonal` brush style does.

[image: Screenshot]

From the wording of your question ("I want to draw a diagonal cross [...]"), I suspect you actually want something else, namely, a big cross inside the rectangle. This you cannot achieve using the standard brushes at all. Rather, you have to draw it manually:

```
procedure TForm4.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R := ClientRect;
  InflateRect(R, -10, -10);
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Rectangle(R);
  Canvas.MoveTo(10, 10);
  Canvas.LineTo(R.Right, R.Bottom);
  Canvas.MoveTo(10, R.Bottom);
  Canvas.LineTo(R.Right, 10);
end;
```

[image: Screenshot]