# Why does TDrawGrid.OnDrawCell draw black background when Brush.Style is bsFDiagonal?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe3

I have the following code (assigned to DrawGrid1.OnDrawCell event):

```
procedure TForm1.DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsFDiagonal;
  DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clSkyBlue;
  DrawGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
end;
```

It always draws black background even if the DrawGrid1.Color properties has been set to clRed. I also tried to change the Pen and Font properties, no luck.
What did I miss here?

[image]

ps: I have checked this code: [Diagonal brush style gives me black area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709166/diagonal-brush-style-gives-me-black-area).
I have failed to see what is the difference between the question and the answer (apart from the commented line) and that code not working for me, as I mentioned, I already tried to change Pen properties without any result.
All I want is red background with sky blue diagonal lines.

Comment: I don't have XE* and can't have a look at the sources myself, but in earlier Delphi versions there was a line in `TCanvas.CreateBrush()` that sets a (wrong) background color to work around a bug in Windows 95 - maybe it's still there? It messes up the color, but you see black because it also messes up the alpha value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, have to add SetBKColor() before FillRect:

```
DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsFDiagonal;
DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clSkyBlue;
SetBkColor(DrawGrid1.Canvas.Handle, ColorToRGB(clRed));
DrawGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
```

I still don't know why, but it's working.

Comment: I guess `SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT)` also works, and would not  touch the background at all.

Comment: Tried SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT), not works for me, background still black.